# React State data not able to be passed as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is my code

```
jobClickedHandler = (event, index) => {
              return (
                    <EditJobScheduler
                          open={this.state.editModalActive}
                          onClose={this.closeEditModal}
                          scheduleJobHandler={this.scheduleJobHandler}
                          inputHandler={this.inputHandler}
                          jobInfo={this.state.jobData[index]}
                    />
              )
        this.setState( { editModalActive: true });
  }
```

The component above receives it's parameters from the click event.

I call this inside of my render method, like so.

```
{this.state.editModalActive && this.jobClickedHandler() }
```

When I call this.jobClickedHandler method as a function, my component errors out that is expecting that data (I cannot access the properties because it is receiving undefined)

Below is the component that is expecting the prop

```
class EditJobScheduler extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { modalActive: false, todayDate: moment() }
  }

  handleChange = (date) => {
    this.setState({
        todayDate: date
    });
  }

  render() {
        console.log(this.props.jobInfo)
        return (
              <Modal
                    open={this.props.open}
                    onClose={this.props.onClose}
              >
                    <form className ="modalForm"onSubmit = {this.props.scheduleJobHandler}>
                          <h2 id = "header">Schedule a new job</h2>
                          {/*<span id= "exit" onClick={this.closeModal}>&#8855;</span>*/}
                          <br />
                           <label>Full Name of Customer</label><br />
                          <input name = "customerName" type = "text" value={this.props.jobInfo.jobName} onChange = {this.props.inputHandler}></input>
                          <br />
                          <br />

                          <label>Job Type</label>
                          <br />
                          <select name = "jobType" onChange = {this.props.inputHandler}>
                                <option selected value = {this.state.jobInfo}></option>
                                <option value = "Plumbing">Plumbing</option>
                                <option value = "Septic">Septic</option>
                                <option value = "Drain">Drain</option>
                          </select>
                          <br />
                          <br />

                          <label>Phone Number</label><br />
                          <input name = "phone" type = "tel" value={this.state.jobInfo.jobPhoneNumber} onChange = {this.props.inputHandler}></input>
                          <br />
                          <br />

                          <label>Job Address</label><br />
                          <input ref = "jobAddress" name="address"type = "text" value={this.props.jobInfo.jobAddress} onChange = {this.props.inputHandler}></input>
                          <br />
                          <br />

                          <label>Assigned Tech</label><br />
                          <select name = "assignedTech" onChange = {this.props.inputHandler}>
                                <option value = {'Select a Tech'}></option>
                                <option value = "Kaleb">Kaleb</option>
                                <option value = "Andrew">Andrew</option>
                                <option value = "John">John</option>
                          </select><br />
                          <br />

                          <label>Date of service</label><br />
                          <DatePicker
                                  selected={this.props.jobInfo.jobDate}
                                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                           />

                          <div className = "submit">
                          <button type = "submit" onClick = {this.props.scheduleJobHandler} className = "btn btn-success">Schedule</button>
                          </div>
                    </form>
              </Modal>
        )
  }
}
```

I'm just trying to fill the input's with the data from state. Any ideas as to why undefined is being passed through my prop instead of the data?

Comment: In `jobClickedHandler`, why are you returning before your call to `setState`?

Comment: show more 'outer component' code - `jobClickedHandler` suggests event handler while it's use doesn't - too many unknown (weird) things

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to join handler and renderer into one method.

It doesn't make sense - handler changes state which will force new render - event if it would work in first pass - next would overwrite it but also call setState and so on...

Just use it separately:

```
jobClickedHandler = (event, index) => {
    this.setState( { editModalActive: true });
}

renderEditModal = () => {
          return (
                <EditJobScheduler
                      open={this.state.editModalActive}
                      onClose={this.closeEditModal}
                      scheduleJobHandler={this.scheduleJobHandler}
                      inputHandler={this.inputHandler}
                      jobInfo={this.state.jobData[index]}
                />
          )
}


{this.state.editModalActive && this.renderEditModal() }
```

I would also decompose content/functional parts to separate components to avoid rerendering of all elements on each state change.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the issue when something like this ends up as undefined is that the "this" isn't bound to a specific object.  For classes that have methods that use "this", especially using react, I would recommend binding them in the constructor.  For example:

```js
class EditJobScheduler extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { modalActive: false, todayDate: moment() };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = (date) => {
    this.setState({
        todayDate: date
    });
  }
```

Something like this binds the method to each instance rather than to the class itself.  I hope this helps.

Comment: I thought with arrow functions, I don't need to bind them since the arrow function does that for me?